# How do you have Play Framework, ReactJS, and Require compile a JS file including dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, playframework

When you create a ReactJS application with Browserify that precompiles your JS file, you can add:

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

and the Browserify compile picks up the react-dom in the compiled output file so that they browser works seemlessly.

If there a way to do the same in a Play Framework application (ie, not use requirejs client side)?